# C# Remoting Gateway / delegate Transparentproxy

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

I like to get some background information, but a not able to find it.
My scenario:

I have a Remoting-Server:

```
public interface IServer
{
    IWorker GetWorker(string strID);
    void Register(IWorker worker);
}
```

I have some "Worker"-Aplications

```
public interface IWorker
{
    string ID { get; }
    void Work(string strData);
}
```

The Server starts the worker-processes, they get a remoting Reference and registers at the Server. The server stores the TransparentProxy's in a Collection.

Now the Client connects to the server, request a Worker. The Server returns the TransparentProxy.

All works fine. But what is happening? Is the client talking with the server when it calls a method on theworker, and the server with the worker? So the Server acts as a "Gateway" or it the client able to comunicate directly with the worker?

Is it the same when i use IPC as with TCP?